# Word replacement while user is typing input (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, html

I have a code that displays what an user is typing and that input is written down back into a  in the html document.

This is the code below:

```
<html><head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.zclip.js"></script>
<style> body{font-family:century gothic;}</style>
</head>
<body style="zoom: 1;">

<div style="padding:10%;">



<textarea type="text" name="fname" class="chatinput" style="margin: 0px; width:   977px; height: 324px;"> </textarea>
<div style="padding-top:10%;" class="printchatbox"></div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.zclip.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$('.chatinput').keyup(function(event) {
newText = event.target.value;
$('.printchatbox').text(newText);
});  
</script>
```

Can someone please help me to figure out how I can make it so that it replaces a word or a line of string into something else live while the user is typing.

For example is the user writes "this is a string" ... the program writes it down on the html document, but also automatically changes that specific string into something like "This is a text" from "This is a string"..
Please help!

Comment: I can't give you an exact code response at the moment, but one (some what inelegant) solution is to turn the input box into a string that is updated on key-up. Then, use a for loop to iterate over an associative array of words and their replacements. Use the .indexOf method to find the words in the input-string, then split the input and concat the desired replacement from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/kndcqqx9/).

I created an object where you can add all the strings you need to replace in a key-value pair. Please keep in mind to escape special characters for RegExp though (with a `\`).

**JS**

```
var replaceValues = {
    'string' : 'text',
    'foo' : 'bar'
}

$('.chatinput').keyup(function (event) {
    newText = event.target.value;
    for (var txt in replaceValues) {
        var temp = new RegExp(txt, 'gim');
        newText = newText.replace(temp, replaceValues[txt]);
    }
    $('.printchatbox').text(newText);
});
```

Comment: Is there any way I can print the replaceValues in a textarea instead of the HTML document itself?

Comment: Try this fork: https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/e9kL6m8s/1/ I changed .printchatbox to a textarea instead of a div. I change the JS as well (.text to .val)

Comment: I've tried that, but for some reason it wan't working when I did it. But again, thanks for your help

Comment: Within Javascript, is there a way to break the text so that they don't appear right next to each other, instead on separate lines?  - Im a noob to JS. sorry.

Comment: Where do you want to place the breaks? can you give an example scenario?

Comment: Like for example when Foo changes to Bar... but is there any way i can add a <br> break point so that when i write String.. its replacement word gets written down below the previous replacement words.. so that its not all in the same line.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, so if I type "test foo", it will show "test <line break here>bar"? Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/hebrpms7/

Comment: Yes thats exactly it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the replace function on your variable.

```
<html><head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.zclip.js"></script>
<style> body{font-family:century gothic;}</style>
</head>
<body style="zoom: 1;">

<div style="padding:10%;">



<textarea type="text" name="fname" class="chatinput" style="margin: 0px; width:   977px; height: 324px;"> </textarea>
<div style="padding-top:10%;" class="printchatbox"></div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.zclip.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$('.chatinput').keyup(function(event) {
newText = event.target.value;
$('.printchatbox').text(newText.replace("This is a string","This is a text"));
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea type="text" name="fname" class="chatinput" style="margin: 0px; width:   977px; height: 324px;"> </textarea>
<div style="padding-top:10%;" class="printchatbox"></div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.chatinput').keyup(function() {
var newText = $('.chatinput').val();
$('.printchatbox').text(newText);
});  
</script>
```