# Real time text box value replace while typing for translator

Tags: jquery, html, replace

First I want to tell you i am a beginner of JQuery. I am trying to build a translator in real time replacement on text box for a example if I typed "A" on text box, that is want to replace to "B".

This is want to check up to 3 words. Which means,

1. If I typed "A" on text box that is want replace to "X"
2. If I typed "AB" on text box that is want to replace to "Y"
3. If I typed "ABZ" on text box that is want to replace to "Z"

Other thing after replacement if I typed middle of some word that also want replacement.
For example if I typed ABZ in between XY, that is want to replace XZY.

HTML Code:

```
<textarea type="text" name="fname" class="chatinput" style="margin: 0px; width:   977px; height: 324px;"> </textarea>
```

Please help to build this using JQuery. I tried to do it by leaning [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834054/word-replacement-while-user-is-typing-input-js) but it is not working.

Comment: if you replace in real time how will you ever type AB if A is replaced with B in real time?

Comment: Ops sorry for that I re correct it. This is for a example only

Comment: your edit didn't answer the question, if A is replaced by anything, how will AB ever be entered, if you enter A it will turn into X....

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L9fe0py3/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dict = [{word:"A",replacement:"B"},{word:"AB",replacement:"C"},{word:"ABZ",replacement:"D"}];
  $('#txt').blur(function(){
        for(var i=0;i<dict.length;i++){
    /*
    If I typed "A" on text box that is want replace to "B"
If I typed "AB" on text box that is want to replace to "C"
If I typed "ABZ" on text box that is want to replace to "D"
    */
        $('#txt').val($('#txt').val().replace(dict[i].word, dict[i].replacement));
    }
  });
});
```

You need to replace the JSON to the characters you need to replace, and when the textbox blur you will have what you want.

Comment: You used capital letters, use capital letters on snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating an array of objects for the keyword and it's translation and iterate through it to replace the words found in the textbox with their translations (if they had one).

But I think we should look for longer words first so that **"CABZB"** will not translate to **"CBBZB"** where "A" is translated first before "ABZ" was checked.

Please see snippet below:

```js
var
  dictionary = [ // Crate array of objects for translation definitions
    {
      word: "A",
      translation: "B"
    }, {
      word: "AB",
      translation: "C"
    }, {
      word: "ABZ",
      translation: "D"
    }
  ],
  $fname = $('#fname'),
  $button = $('#translate');

// Sort dictionary so that longer words are checked first in looping later
dictionary.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.word.length - a.word.length;
});

$button.click(function() {
  var text = $fname.val();

  // Loop through each item in dictionary and replace where found (prioritizing longer words)
  $.each(dictionary, function(k, v) {
    var regex = new RegExp(v.word, "gim"); // convert keyword to regex (currently case-insensitive)
    text = text.replace(regex, v.translation);
  });

  $fname.val(text);
});
```

```css
.chatinput {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="fname" type="text" name="fname" class="chatinput"></textarea>
<br>
<button id="translate">Translate</button>
```

Honestly, in my opinion, we should not loop through the whole dictionary since it would probably become very slow (the dictionary would tend to be very large if it would contain a lot of translations), but to comply with your need that words would be searched and translated within words (like the "CABZB" to "CDB"), it had to be done (I'm not sure if there are better ways but this is what I came up with at the moment).

If you there is no actual need to translate within words, then I think it's best to loop through each word in the textbox rather than the whole dictionary.

I hope this helps.